# Which of these two options is more load time efficient for MySQL table design?

Tags: mysql, database-design, load

This is a website question takes into account caching and number of queries, besides correct database design.

Would it be generally more efficient to 1) put all fields for each institution in to one database, 2) divide the information into two tables, the first table would have the information that will be used the most often.

The project lists up to 100 records of a specific type of organization with numerous fields that help a viewer choose the organization that best meets their needs.

Currently, there are about 40 fields, but this is subject to change.

There is an "index" page that lists about 10 fields for each institution. Since this is one of the most used pages on the site, with few data changes, caching is a factor.

The "index" page clicks to a page with all the particulars. For the individual institution pages, data would come from two tables and there would be either two database queries or a join type query.

An additional issue on page load is that this information will be delivered through an iFrame from a shared hosting site into a web service site. This setup is, unfortunately not negotiable, but it does add to the page load concerns.

I have done a little research, but most of the replies are for a database design that does not follow basic normalization. Possibly with the small amount of data, my question is irrelevant.

Comment: i don't believe that you would notice any difference, usually the problme starts with huge data in the millions. But if you want it fast and you don't have too many data, use a in memory Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds to me like premature optimization.  Unless you're talking about a website with millions of hits per hour, I would start simply with a single table (that's what I assume when you wrote database) that has all the 40 fields, and that you can simply expand in the future.  Also, your front-end UI should be able to optimize the requests to the database, so it only needs to refresh sporadically.

Speaking from experience, it's a pain to have to handle primary and secondary tables, specifically when you're updating/deleting data, as well as the fact that every single query that needs access to even 1 of the fields in the secondary table, will now require a join.  So unless it's absolutely required, you should not do it.

Better to keep all the record in the one table, and if you need to, you can always add fields to that table in the future.

Comment: A possible exception is for _very_ active columns such as "likes" or "click_count".